# simplifying values in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

my table looks like this:

```
|    col1     | col2    | col3    |
| xxx001xxx1  | ...     | ...     |
| xxx001xxx2  | ...     | ...     |
| xxx001xxx3  | ...     | ...     |
| xxx002xxx1  | ...     | ...     |
| xxx002xxx2  | ...     | ...     |
| xxx003xxx1  | ...     | ...     |
```

i want to update the table, so it will be look like this:

```
|    col1     | col2    | col3    |
|     1       | ...     | ...     |
|     1       | ...     | ...     |
|     1       | ...     | ...     |
|     2       | ...     | ...     |
|     2       | ...     | ...     |
|     3       | ...     | ...     |
```

any suggestions?

Comment: is that format always exactly how the values appear? `XXX000XXX0`?

Comment: do you also want to change the column data type?

Comment: @Tanner yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql):

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, 4,3) AS INT) AS col1, col2, col3
FROM tab_name;
```

And `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tab_name
SET col1 = CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, 4,3) AS INT);
```

**EDIT:**

> my table got 600 entries and i want no leading zeros for the smaller numbers

There wont't be leading zeros: **[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/MSW23359)**

Comment: my table got 600 entries and i want no leading zeros for the smaller numbers

Comment: @jimmmmyjooo You don't get leading zeros

Comment: i only get zeros in col1

Comment: Please check my demo. If your format is as in question `xxx002xxx2` then you should get your values, if not you have to adjust query.

Comment: it is for example "CounterStat_St028Lane02" and i used CAST(SUBSTRING(col1, 15,3) AS INT);

Comment: @jimmmmyjooo And you get `28` as in demo http://rextester.com/USNYD88478

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy when the numbers are always in the right spot. For fun, here's how you' solve this for the following sample data:

**Sample data**

```
col1
--------------
xxx001xxx1
xxxx005xxx2
xxxxxx0010xxx3
xxx00015xxx1
xxx00007xxx2
xxx0033xxx1
```

**Solution**

```
-- sample data
declare @sometable table (col1 varchar(100));
insert @sometable
values ('xxx001xxx1'), ('xxxx005xxx2'), ('xxxxxx0010xxx3'), 
       ('xxx00015xxx1'), ('xxx00007xxx2'), ('xxx0033xxx1');

-- solution
with prep as ( select col1, nbrStart = substring(col1, patindex('%[0-9][0-9]%',col1), 100)
               from @sometable)
select col1,
       nbr = cast(substring(nbrStart, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', nbrStart)-1) as int)
from prep;
```

**Results**

```
col1                               nbr
---------------------------------- -----------
xxx001xxx1                         1
xxxx005xxx2                        5
xxxxxx0010xxx3                     10
xxx00015xxx1                       15
xxx00007xxx2                       7
xxx0033xxx1                        33
```